# In order to transfer app from one Google Play Dev account to another do I need the App key?

Tags: android, google-play

I need to transfer an app from one Google Play Dev account to another, I already have all the necessary info in order to request the transfer, but after that am I going to be able to send updates of that specific app or I'll need other informations like the the key with which the app has been exported?

Comment: I think that you have to transfer the signature file if you about it.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to transfer an app from one Dev Account to Another, in order to continue publishing updates to your users, you need to keep rhe same couple packageName and Signature. In fact this couple is the only key that allows Google to ensure unicity of an app.
That means that if you cannot obtain signature files along with the transfer you will not be able to publish updates and you will have to release a new app with a new packageName.